# Issues with my File manager - Files

Tags: unity, files

While a window of the File manager is opened, on clicking the files icon, in Unity, should open the minimised screen. But Files application opens another new Window.
This is reaally annoying as I end up 2 or 3 Windows while I was trying to open a minimised Window.

I checked Preferences but I got no clue. 
I am using Ubuntu 14.04
Files Version : 3.10.1